# Fetching Nuget update list takes very long time

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio, if I right click a project and select "Manage NuGet Packages", it takes 1-2 minutes to bring up a list of updates.

My projects have around 30 nuget packages installed (I shouldnt think that's enough to justify 2 minutes of version checking)

If I go to the Installed tab, some of the packages show an up arrow, so it already knows which packages need updates... So why does the Updates tab take forever?

Additionally, if I close the Nuget screen and reopen... The updates tab will take another 2 minutes to load, even though 10 seconds ago it had fetched the list.

Things I have tried:

- Updated the NuGet.exe in .nuget folder to latest
- Gone to Tools - Options - Nuget Package Manager - General - Clear All NuGet Cache
- Gone to Tools - Options - Nuget Package Manager - Package Sources - Update

I am using VS 2019 16.11.1

I have tried VS 2022 Preview 3.1, but the nuget updates screen won't load even after waiting 5min (then I gave up and went back to 2019)

Is there a way I can speed up fetching the list of Nuget Updates?

Answer (score 1):

Although the checking time will become longer if more NuGet packages have been installed, I believe this is a potential issue, and at least checking for a long time every time may not be a good experience.

I have reported this issue to Microsoft Developer Community, and here is the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/nuget-package-manager-takes-too-much-time-to-load/1506629?from=email).

I have checked the related options about setting NuGet and NuGet Package Manager but indeed there are fewer options to set. And I think re-check/reload the `Updates` list is by design and cannot be changed by simply changing a single option. But perhaps there are still something that we can do:

1). Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources > Only choose and select the used Source, such as `nuget.org` and `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages`.

2). Right-click project > Manage NuGet Packages… > on the top right corner, select `nuget.org` instead of `All`.(This should be based on the specific requirement)